# How to sort multidimensional array by name/timestamp?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I were using the "rsort" function to sort through the timestamps when the array only contained a timestamp and were not multidimensional.

So now the question is how do i approach this?

The array looks something similair to this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [id] => 1
            [timestamp] => 2017-08-12 21:03:22
            [poster] => 1
            [profile] => 1
            [post] => Testtttttinngggs
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [id] => 2
            [timestamp] => 2017-08-12 21:03:18
            [poster] => 1
            [profile] => 5
            [post] => Hello you
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [id] => 3
            [timestamp] => 2017-08-12 21:03:33
            [poster] => 1
            [profile] => 1
            [post] => Somesay timestamp is screwed
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [id] => 4
            [timestamp] => 2017-08-12 21:28:54
            [poster] => 1
            [profile] => 1
            [post] => This is truely a teeest
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [id] => 5
            [timestamp] => 2017-08-13 15:04:34
            [poster] => 1
            [profile] => 1
            [post] => Test test test test
        )

)
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate? all other questions i could find was a Javascript question..

Comment: Did you *look* at the duplicate (linked at the top of your question)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **array_multisort**

```
array_multisort(array_column($list, 'timestamp'), SORT_ASC, $list);
```

Comment: @Javaish Rob Ruchte's answer will easily outperform this one because it doesn't require PHP to first extract the `timestamp` into a separate column array, and then execute the multisort ( `array_multisort` is itself a more complex function than Rob's simple comparator).  This answer looks sexy, but is a lot less efficient.

Comment: @BeetleJuice run both approaches on my machine 1Mil times. My approach took 1.845 seconds. Rob's approach took 16.883182048798 seconds. You may be right though if you are about space complexity. `usort` is known as very and very slow.

Comment: That's a shocker. Hang on let me test

Comment: @BeetleJuice https://pastebin.com/DZ9pgQbi

Comment: Axalix you're right!  Just ran 100,000 iterations of each approach and `array_multisort` is faster; **much** faster -- takes only about 1/7th the time.  How could that be??

Comment: PHP magic - I faced this issue a while ago and was also surprised. `array_multisort` is also nice because you can sort an array by many (_multiple_) fields like in `ORDER BY A ASC, B DESC, ...` sql syntax.

Comment: @BeetleJuice The overhead of repeatedly invoking the comparator most likely…

Answer (score 1):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, function($a, $b)
{
    if($a['timestamp']>$b['timestamp'])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    elseif($a['timestamp']<$b['timestamp'])
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

I was wrong. Axalix' answer runs a lot faster than mine and Rob Ruchte's.  My tests:

```
$data = [
    ['timestamp'=> '2015-08-12', 'id'=>1],
    ['timestamp'=> '2017-07-13', 'id'=>2],
    ['timestamp'=> '2017-01-12', 'id'=>3],
];

function useUsort($data){
  usort($data,function($a,$b) {
    return strtotime($b['timestamp']) - strtotime($a['timestamp']);
  });
};
function useMultisort($data){
  array_multisort(array_column($data, 'timestamp'), SORT_DESC, $data);
};

$start = microtime(true);
for($i=1;$i<=100000;$i++) useUsort($data);
$t1 = microtime(true);
for($i=1;$i<=100000;$i++) useMultisort($data);
$t2 = microtime(true);

echo "usort:           ". round(($t1 - $start) * 1000) . " ms\n";
echo "array_multisort: ". round(($t2 - $t1) * 1000) . " ms\n";
```

My result:

```
usort:           2262 ms
array_multisort: 246 ms
```

#### Original answer

@Axalix' answer is nice but I would take a different approach. Because you only care about sorting by one field (timestamp), `array_multisort` is overkill as it was design to sort by multiple fields. I would do:

```
usort($data,function($a,$b) {
    return strtotime($b['timestamp']) - strtotime($a['timestamp']);
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bad03a4e5c20b6d08dd1290ab9cae39a0983a23)

This will easily outperform `array_multisort` because it doesn't require PHP to first extract the `timestamp` into a separate column array, and then execute the multisort (a more complex function than my simple comparator function) on it.